# Selecting a specific string before/ after a character ("-") in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I've used substring to get the first and the last value. But how can I find a specific character in a string and fetch the values before/ after it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try these ... it sounds like what you are looking for

reference docs:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.substring_index
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('hello-there',)], ['text'])

from pyspark.sql.functions import substring_index
df.select(substring_index(df.text, '-', 1).alias('left')).show() # left of delim
df.select(substring_index(df.text, '-', -1).alias('right')).show() # right of delim

+-----+
| left|
+-----+
|hello|
+-----+

+-----+
|right|
+-----+
|there|
+-----+

from pyspark.sql.functions import split
split_df = df.select(split(df.text, '-').alias('split_text'))
split_df.selectExpr("split_text[0] as left").show() # left of delim
split_df.selectExpr("split_text[1] as right").show() # right of delim

+-----+
| left|
+-----+
|hello|
+-----+

+-----+
|right|
+-----+
|there|
+-----+

from pyspark.sql.functions import substring_index, substring, concat, col, lit

df = spark.createDataFrame([('will-smith',)], ['text'])

df = df\
.withColumn("left", substring_index(df.text, '-', 1))\
.withColumn("right", substring_index(df.text, '-', -1))\

df = df\
.withColumn("left_sub", substring(df.left, -2, 2))\
.withColumn("right_sub", substring(df.right, 1, 2))

df = df\
.withColumn("concat_sub", concat(col("left_sub"), lit("-"), col("right_sub")))

df.show()

+----------+----+-----+--------+---------+----------+
|      text|left|right|left_sub|right_sub|concat_sub|
+----------+----+-----+--------+---------+----------+
|will-smith|will|smith|      ll|       sm|     ll-sm|
+----------+----+-----+--------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: How can I fetch only the two values before & after the delimiter. For ex. (lo-th) as an output in a new column

Comment: i have updated my answer to give you your requested output (lo-th) ... please take a look and consider marking as correct answer ... i hope this helps @KatelynRaphael

Comment: I've 100 records separated with a delimiter ("-"). For ex. ['hello-there', 'will-smith', 'ariana-grande', 'justin-bieber']. So, I've to fetch the two letter left/right of the delimiter ['lo-th', 'll-sm', 'na-gr', 'in-bi']. As my data is changing, how can I find a delimiter and then fetch the 2 letter to the left & right?

Comment: k ... i updated answer ... using -2, 2 will give last 2 chars in string and 1, 2 will give first 2 chars in string so different string lengths won't cause any problems now @KatelynRaphael